# Assembly scan and register class against interface at dotnet core

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-assembly

See the following code:

```
public interface IUserRepository:IRepository<User>
{

}

public abstract class GenericRepository<TEntity,Tkey>:IRepository<TEntity>,IDisposable
where TEntity:BaseEntity<Tkey> 
where Tkey:class


public class UserRepository : GenericRepository<User, string>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(SecurityDb dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }
}
```

My Question is: I want to find the `UserRepository` through `GenericRepository<>`  and `IUserRepository` through `IRepository<>`. So I make this function:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddIgidiaService(this IServiceCollection service,IEnumerable<Assembly> Assemblies)
    {

       var types= Assemblies.SelectMany(a=>a.ExportedTypes).ToArray();
       var repositories= types.Where(t=>typeof(GenericRepository<,>).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(t.GetTypeInfo()))
       .Where(t => !t.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract);
       var irepositories=types.Where(t=>typeof(IRepository<>).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(t.GetTypeInfo()))
            .Where(t=>t.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface);
            foreach (var repository in repositories)
            {
                foreach (var irepositoriy in irepositories)
                {
                    if (repository.GetTypeInfo().IsInstanceOfType(irepositoriy))
                    {
                        service.AddScoped(repository,irepositoriy);
                    }
                }
            }
        return service;
    }
```

This code does not work as I want it to.

Comment: Please add exception details, as it is not clear what is not working

Comment: This code work without any exception but just the result not show as i imagine